# cell editor query in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a table where in I am using a common cell editor field  for each column initialized with different instances of-course.

Now ,if I have an entry in the table having multiple columns and if a row entry is being used then if the user tries to edit the row ,let say the name field,by clicking on the cell editor
then we show a dialog saying the entry is in use hence cannot change.

But, When I click on the name field to change it and immediately click on the next column adjacent to the name field ,let say address, then before the pop up comes the address field shows the name instead of address and untill we click on "ok" on the pop-up dialog then value of address shows the name field value and once we close the dialog the address values reappears.

How to keep it consistent so that address field value wont get changed with the name field value?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.